# Multiple domains on single VPS droplet

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vps, digital-ocean

I have a VPS droplet with Digital Ocean.

I host my personal website (personalweb.site) on it with node and express.

My express app.js file looks like below:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', '80');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //my personal site files live here

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  var port = server.address().port;
}
```

I push my content up to my VPS droplet through ssh with rsync. My local folder structure matches that of my VPS droplet.

```
cloud/
|── node_modules/
|── public/
|   |── js/
|   |── css/
|   |── index.html
|── app.js
|── Gruntfile.js
|── package.json
```

Then I start the server from my root directory with `node app.js &` *(I use **&** to keep the process running after I close that terminal window.)*

My question is, how can I host another website (friendweb.site) on my VPS droplet?

**EDIT:** How about a simple comment explanation as to why a question is "bad", rather than downvoting because you don't have the answer to a question.

Comment: You're getting voted down because it is (a) off-topic as we are not Digital Ocean support, and (b) solvable in 10 seconds with Google (see any of the top **eight** hits for your title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to face a few challenges if you try to simply run a second node app and host it on your server.  Btw, this has very little to do with Digital Ocean, if at all.

The biggest challenge you'll face is that you can't have both apps listening on port 80, only one app wins.  So unless you want users to see a different port number as part of the URL (I doubt that's the case), you'll need to look at setting up a reverse proxy of some kind.  This can be achieved with [Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) or [nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) for example.  This way both domains can point to the same public IP, both node apps can listen on different ports, and the reverse proxy takes care of routing requests to each one based on the hostname requested.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does that mean I will need to replace my "express" set up with Apache / nginx? Or do I install it and use Apache in addition to express?

Comment: You'll still need express to run your separate node apps.  App 1 might end up listening on port 8080 for example, while App 2 might end up listening on port 8081.  Apache or nginx would be the one listening on port 80, routing traffic which ever app the request needs to go do.

Comment: Thanks again dude - I used this tutorial specifically to get it working, based on your advice. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts - You've been a great help and saved me tons of time!

Comment: :-D that's awesome!